# Conversion from cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a cell array of 150 by 1 . My problem is why cant we use the eq function, as in 
the value of `species(1) = 'setosa'`,
but when I write `species(1) == 'setosa'` I was expecting to get a logical `1` but MATLAB gives `Undefined function eq for cell array` . I require this because I want to convert it into a logical array . How should I achieve this

Comment: PS: the answer to your prevous question is `grp2idx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `find()` and `strcmp()` together.

Example:

```
stts = {'Gable','Hip','Shed','Shed','Other'}; % string cell array
[truefalse,index]=find(strcmp(stts,'Shed')) % do it here if you want to find `Shed`
```

After this, `truefalse` are the logical values and `index` are the according indexes found.

```
truefalse =

     1     1


index =

     3     4
```

Comment: I am having one more problem the first 50 elements are 'setosa' that is why I am getting index = 50